# Address and port of unconnected SSLSocket

Tags: java, sockets, client, sslsocketfactory

I’d like to create an unconnected SSLSocket (and I can using the SSLSocketFactory createSocket() method) but then I need to specify address and port to connect the socket. But, apparently there’s not a way to do so. Why? So why this method exists?

It looks like it works with a Socket, you can create a Socket and then connect it toward a server, but not with a SSLSocket. The only way seems to be to use the SSLSocketFactory createSocket method passing there address and port to connect to, but if I want my socket to be unconnected at the beginning, is there a way?

Comment: You would [bind](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Socket.html#bind(java.net.SocketAddress)) it to the [address](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but as far as I understood, binding is for servers. I need a SSLSocket acting as a client.

Comment: Could I use the connect() method and then startHandshake()?

Comment: *'binding is for servers'* - not so.  It is perhaps less usual to bind a client TCP socket to a particular network address and even less usual to bind it to a particular TCP port, but there's nothing to stop you.

Comment: There is a perfectly useful no-args call to createSocket that creates an unconnected SSLSocket, e.g. `SSLSocket sock = (SSLSocket) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket();`.

Comment: But how can I connect to a remote address and port the socket?